# How to get the mobile number and date of birth from google profile using Google+ api in java?

Tags: java, google-api

I have used the G+ api and also got the use profile but I am not able to fetch the mobile number and date of birth. The data that I got in response consists of email,display name,given name,gender,profile image. If any one have got mobile number,date of birth then please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Phone number and birthday are not available in the [data returned](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource) from the Google+ API. You're best option is probably to ask users to manually enter the info.